# Excel 2003 difference between .xlm behaviour

Tags: excel, vba, xlm

I have two Excel 2003 .xlm files, each with one makro. The text in both macros is the same. I run macros from workmap (.xls file) with only one sheet. Cells in .xls file are preformatted, vor example Cell(1, 5) has Custom Format `"MMMM"`.

The first thing the macro does is to put value in preformatted cell in .xls file, for example with the command: `Cells(1, 5).Value = "01.11.2010"`.

If I do it with one .xlm file, the result is `"November"`.

If I do it with another .xlm file, the result is `"01.11.2010"`.

Other preformatted cells working differently too. If I put in cell the value "8,00", first .xlm put it as number, the second as a text. It goes even the both .xlm files are opened.

What could be the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Please consider posting a link to your workbooks (via DropBox or GoogleDocs). It will be easier to troubleshoot with all of these information.

Comment: the column format mask appears to be different.

Answer (score 1):

Regional settings play a factor here so my setup may be a bit different than what you have.  However in A2 I keyed in 1/11/2012.  I set B2 formula = A2 and C2 formula = A2.

Notice how the display is different for each of the two results.  This is because I have formatted the columns B and C to be in different display (masks) formats.

It is possible you have a similar issue on the sheet with "NOVEMBER" being displayed.

[image]